# Использование readUnsignedInt

Tags: c#

Помогите, как использовать readUnsignedInt, readUTF, writeUnsignedInt и т.п в C#?
Выдает ошибку

> Ошибка CS1061  "NetworkStream" не содержит определения для "ReadUnsignedInt", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "ReadUnsignedInt", принимающий тип "NetworkStream" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleServer
{
    public class ClientObject
    {
        public TcpClient client;
        public ClientObject(TcpClient tcpClient)
        {
            client = tcpClient;
        }

        public void Process()
        {
            NetworkStream stream = null;
            try
            {
                stream = client.GetStream();
                string member_type = "new";
                int bytes = 0;
                while (true)
                {   
                    if (member_type == "new")
                    {
                        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                        bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

                        Console.WriteLine(message);
                        if (message == "<policy-file-request/>\0")
                        {
                            // отправляем обратно сообщение в верхнем регистре
                            message = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"11111\" /></cross-domain-policy>\0";
                            data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                            member_type = "client";
                        }
                    } else {
                        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                        bytes = data.readUnsignedBytes();
                        Console.WriteLine(bytes);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (stream != null)
                    stream.Close();
                if (client != null)
                    client.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Сначала я отправляю crossdomain, а затем хочу получить Uint из потока

Comment: кроме текста ошибки нужен ваш код

Comment: Я имею ввиду какую библиотеку нужно using, в которой содержится ReadUnsignedInt?

Comment: Вы нас спрашиваете, какая **вам** библиотека нужна?

Comment: Полагаю, вам нужен класс [BinaryReader](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader?view=netframework-4.7.2), у него есть множество методов `Read*`